# Highlight Blank Text Boxes

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a table, and certain text boxes within the table are submited as part of a form:

I have created the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrgLG/1/) as a demo.

Would anyone be able to help?  I would like any text boxes that are empty when the `Process Now` button is clicked to be highlighted in red - and for the form to not submit and alert the user.

If there are any further questions, just ask.

Comment: Brother You have missed the Id name in Input type Button. Thats the reason your code was not working...

Comment: D'oh!  Well that would be the reason.... I need a break!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works, the problem is because you did not add the `id` to your button:

```
<input type="SUBMIT" name="ProcessNow" id="ProcessNow" value="Process Now" style="width:100px;height:30px">
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SrgLG/2/)

That being said, it's better to use add/remove classes in your JS. That way all styling can be done in CSS and you don't need to dig through your JS to amend the design of the site. Try this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
        isValid = false;
        $(this).addClass('empty');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

```css
.empty {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SrgLG/3/)

Comment: That is a much neater solution - is it possible to add a message when one is empty saying `"You have a blank text box?"`.

Comment: Absolutely, you can place whatever code is required within the if condition.

Comment: Okay, one final problem.  I have applied this to my webpage and when I click the `Process Now` button, it highlights the textboxes, but continues to process the page.  How can I add a stop?  So the user can go back to edit the boxes?

Comment: At the end of the `#ProcessNow` click handler, add the following line:  `!isValid && e.preventDefault();` This will stop the submit event if the form is not valid.

Comment: Magic!  That worked a treat :)  Thanks @RoryMcCrossan